# Getting Access Token for Microsoft Graph from asp.net core2 Authentication web app

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-2.0

I have created a new asp.net core 2 web application. I'm using individual user accounts and added my Microsoft account for external authentication. All of this works like expected.

Now I want to use Microsoft Graph to read my .live profile and eventually read my mailbox and things like that.

I created an authentication provider and I'm able to get an access token back but why I try to use the access token, I'm getting an Authorization_IdentityNotFound error although my clientId and secret is correctly entered.

I think it's caused by the fact that I'm not using the proper parameters to request the access token. I think I'm missing the authorization response code that is normally returned when I sign into my .live account.

Does anyone know how to retrieve that response code or has a working example in asp.net core2. The only sample I can find is in .net core 1.1 and things have changed rather drastically since then.

Comment: Some sample code and detail on how you registered would help

Comment: I created an IAuthenticationprovider
AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoft.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token");

Comment: I created an IAuthenticationprovider
AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoft.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token");
ClientCredential creds = new ClientCredentials(cid, secret);
authenticationresult ar=await ac.acquiretokenasync("https://graph.microsoft.com/",creds);
request.headers.authorization = new system.net.http.headers.authenticationheadervalue("bearer",ar.accesstoken);
then I make request:
client.users["..."].request().getasync();

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing a few different systems here.

In order to access Microsoft Graph API you'll need to pass an **Access Token** in the `authorization` header of your call. This is used to both provide Microsoft Graph with your identification as well where you're data is stored (you're tenant).

The actual **Access Token** isn't issued by Microsoft Graph, it is issued by your tenant. For work/school accounts this is the Azure Active Directory tenant where your account lives. For personal account this is the Outlook.com tenant.

Prior to receiving an **Access Token**, you first retrieve an **Authorization Code**. This is returned to the `redirect_url` you passed to `login.microsoftonline.com` after you've entered your credentials. Your app then takes this **Authorization Code** and exchanges it for an **Access Token** that you'll use to call Microsoft Graph.

If you're looking for a [authentication library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-libraries) to handle this process, you should use [MSAL.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client). You can find instructions for using this library in the [microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet) repository on GitHub.

Once you have a token, you can either call Microsoft Graph directly or you can leverage the [Microsoft Graph Client Library for .NET](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet).

Comment: Thank you Marc, It's difficult to post all the code because I don't have enough reputation to do so. I understand where to get the access token, i'm getting it now from azure but probably need to get it from outlook.com (what is the url?). You are correct that I need to retrieve the authorization code but that's the problem... I don't know how to do this! I have a callback registered to /signin-microsoft but this is internal to the core library. I'll take a lok MSAL.NET, I just whished that no so much is abstracted away in asp.net core

Comment: Take a look at http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/ for a walk through of how the v2 Endpoint works and the calls required to authenticate.

Comment: Thanks again Marc, I understand the flow better now. But that doesn't get me any closer to understanding exactly how to get the authorization code. Any chance on providing me with some code on that?

Comment: You simply redirect the user to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` along with your app params and it returns the authorization code back to your app via the redirect_uri.

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for your continued patience, but it's not that simple. Like stated before the sign in is redirected /signin-Microsoft. I can't find this "thing" anywhere in my code and I can't change it either. I used this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?tabs=aspnetcore2x to set it up.

Comment: I found that the asp.net core 1.1 sample gets the code in the "configureservices" method on startup. It uses the OnAuthorizationCodeReceived event for this. in asp.net core 2, I don't use the openId connector but the "microsoftaccount"  connector. Can you point me in the right direction on how to get the authorization code with this connector.

Comment: I tried https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp but it's also outdated. Using "UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication" in asp.net core gives "obsolete" error.

Comment: I believe you're overthinking this: 1) Open `authorize` in a browser, 2) get back the auth code, 3) `POST` this code to `token`, 4) get back an access (aka bearer) token. You don't handle step 1 in code, the user clicks a link in your page/app.

Comment: Hi Marc, maybe we are misunderstanding each other. I'm using the asp.net core2 template with individual accounts. On that template I have configured 2 fa with Microsoft account. I created a user, then registered a login on this user (consumer account). That will indeed launch an authorize request in a browser. After authorization I'm redirected to the home page of the application. What I want to do now is to use that same login to get data from Microsoft Graph. My problem is that I don't know how to perform step 2 in your flow... "get back the auth code"... where can I do this?

Comment: basically I think my problem is that I want to get the authorization code from AddMicrosoftAccount. All the samples I can find use AddOpenIdConnect. But the two are completely differently implemented, AddMicrosoftAccount has the OnTicketReceived event, while open id has the OnAuthorizationCodeReceived event. I can't find any documentation on OnTicketReceived. I really want to solve this!